# Background gradient mask layer effect

Tags: gimp, mask, blending

I'm a newbie using gimp. I would like to make a banner like the picture below, a white color banner with some fade background color. Please advise. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Can you Please Explain more about it? , I think it's Portion of Banner, provide more information about it

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `inner glow` or `inner shadow` ...or a bit different: `feathering` / `feathered edge`.

Answer (score 1):

There may be scripts to do it but it can be done manually

- Get a selection on the light color (that can be the one you just used to bucket-fill)
- `Select>Save to channel` to save the selection
- `Select>Invert`
- `Select>Grow` and grow it by the width of the fade you want
- `Select>Feather` by the double of the value above: you know have a selection that fades out starting on the border
- Open the Channels list, right click the `Selection mask copy` and  `Intersect with selection`: so you only keep the fading part of that selection.
- **Important**: in the Layers list, select your layer again
- Bucket-fill the selection with the darker color

[image]